# Xcode Window Layout: How do I open all files in the same window?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have problem with my Xcode window layout. The Group files on the left side is split and when I open the file it open's in a separate window. I want to open the files in same window attach to the group.

Please let me know how to do this.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You must have all projects closed to make this change. Open Xcode Preferences, from the "General" tab select Layout: All-In-One.

Answer (score 0):

You unsplit the Group window using the little icon at the top of its scroll bar.